# Does the using statement dispose only the first variable it create?

Tags: c#, idisposable, using

Let's say I have a disposable object `MyDisposable` whom take as a constructor parameter another disposable object.

```
using(MyDisposable myDisposable= new MyDisposable(new AnotherDisposable()))
{
     //whatever
}
```

Assuming `myDisposable` don't dispose the `AnotherDisposable` inside it's dispose method.

Does this only dispose correctly `myDisposable`? or it dispose the `AnotherDisposable` too?

Comment: Yes, it does, it does not dispose the `AnotherDisposable`, you need to manage manually

Comment: `AnotherDisposable` **should** be disposed on `MyDisposable` implementation since its used in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`using` is an equivalent of

```
MyDisposable myDisposable = new MyDisposable(new AnotherDisposable());
try
{
    //whatever
}
finally
{
    if (myDisposable != null)
        myDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

Thus, if `myDisposable` does not call Dispose on `AnotherDisposable`, `using` won't call it either.

Answer (score 5):

Why not nest them?

```
using(var outer = new AnotherDisposable())
{
   using(var inner = new MyDisposable(outer))
   {
      //whatever
   }

}
```

Now at least you can be sure they'll be disposed off correctly.

Comment: the problem is that using the double using makes FxCop show the CA2202: object shouldn't be disposed multiple time, but that's because in the real case I'm using I know the innerDisposable is disposed by the outerDisposable so i guessed if this can be done

Comment: +1, best way to handle cleanup. As a note, the second set of brackets are not even required. It comes down to your formatting preference but you can stack using statements directly on top of each other and use the same brackets to denote the scope.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "dispose" anything. It calls the `Dispose` method of the object used within it. Its your job to clean up anything else.. perhaps by calling dispose on the other object.

Answer (score 1):

C#’s using statement provides a syntactic shortcut for calling Dispose on objects
that implement IDisposable, using a try/finally block. For example:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream ("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
// ... Write to the file ...
}
```

The compiler converts this to:
FileStream fs = new FileStream ("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open);

```
try
{
// ... Write to the file ...
}
finally
{
if (fs != null) ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
}
```

The finally block ensures that the Dispose method is called even when an exception
is thrown,1 or the code exits the block early.

So for using single block will only ensure that the single disposable object will be disposed. on the other hand you can use a nested using statements. like

```
using (myDisposable d = new myDisposable())
{
  using(Disposable2 d2 = new Disposable2())
  {
// do something and dispose...
  }
}
```

and this will be converted as

```
try
{
  // work around for myDisposable  

    try
     {
      // work around for Disposable2 
     }
    finally
    {
    if (d2 != null) 
         ((IDisposable)d2 ).Dispose();
    }    
}
finally
{
     if (d!= null)
          ((IDisposable)d).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it won't dispose the `AnotherDisposable`. There are two solutions to this.

First, what you would normally do is the following:

```
using (AnotherDisposable anotherDisposable = new AnotherDisposable())
using (MyDisposable myDisposable= new MyDisposable(anotherDisposable))
{
}
```

However, there is a different way to go. It's normal that when a class takes a disposable, it itself will take care of disposing the object it took. E.g. the `StreamReader` that wraps a `Stream` will dispose of the `Stream` it wraps. That means that the construct you choose would work. You can implement this same feature in `MyDisposable` and then the approach you took will be OK.

Comment: The pattern `using (MyDisposable myDisposable = new MyDisposable(new AnotherDisposable()) {...}` pattern will only be safe if the constructor for `MyDisposable` promises not only that `MyDisposable.Dispose` will dispose the object passed into the constructor, but also that if any exception occurs during the constructor itself the passed-in item will be disposed immediately--a pattern which is much harder than it should be to get right.

Answer (score 0):

You only initialized one disposable variable in the `using` statement. The `AnotherDisposable` nested object is created through normal initialization, not by `using`. So only the `myDisposable` variable you created with the `using` statement will automatically be disposed by it.